# Can you read the spaces or tabs in the beginning of a line in a file?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, if-statement, printing

So I've been trying to see if I can find the tabs or the spaces of a file. I used this for now and I can't figure it out how am I supposed to call the space or tab or how to find it.

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
    for space in line:
        if line.find("    "):
            print("This is something I want to add to the line",line)
#line in print is the rest of that line that has a tab or spaces in front of the text.
```

File Data:

```
Names: / Status: 

John
      unavailable 
          unavailable

Mike
      available

Jack
      available
```

The tabs from the Status column I need to find a way to read them. One line may have multiple tabs.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the space or tab"? Find them; remove them?

Comment: I think it would be a little clearer if you also showed your expected output. Your code is quite broken...

Comment: @Iosif Livadaru Thanks for accepting!  An upvote would also be appreciated :P

Comment: @Iosif Livadaru  Thank you, sir!

Comment: @frank Your answer was pretty good. this is what I ended up with: space = line.find("\t\t")   if space:
            print("THIS IS A TAB",line[:])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
    for space in line:
        idx = line.find("    ")
        if idx:
            print("This is something I want to add to the line", idx) 
        # Not sure what you want at the end here, but idx will give you the index
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `line.find("\t")` to find tab